# vue not loading data into child component

Tags: image, vue.js, vue-props

I've a hard time in understanding the methods of vue. In my put-request users can edit, delete images. In parent component the get-request loads the images and the are pushed to an image-gallery (the child-component) via properties. In my set up the console.log is always empty.

```
//PARENT COMPONENT
<template>
   <div class="form-group">
   <image-gallery :serverData="serverMap"/>
</div>    
</template>
<script>
   import ImageGallery from './ImageGallery.vue';

   export default {
   components:{ImageGallery},

data: () => ({
    serverMap: {
        title: '',
        file: ''
    } 

}),
mounted () {
    //AJAX ETC get servermap

    .then((response) => {
        this.serverMap = response.data
    })
}
```

Just a normal straight parent-child situation. Here under the child-component

```
<template>

</template>
<script>
export default {
name: 'ImageGallery',

//incoming data
props: {
    serverData: {
        type: Object,
        default () {
            return {
                hasLabels: true,
                isHorizontal: false
            }
        }
    }
},



created: function () {
    this.loadImages()
},
methods: {
    loadImages () {
        console.log(this.serverData.file)
        //do something with the serverData

        //prepare for fileReader function
        //together with new image validation
    }
}
```

The method 'loadImages' should be automatically delevering the serverData via computed.But is doesn t. Who can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is race condition.

Either not render a child until data is available; `serverMap` needs to be null instead of empty object in order to be distinguished from populated object:

```
<image-gallery v-if="serverMap" :serverData="serverMap"/>
```

Or delay data access in a child until it's available instead of doing this immediately in `created`:

```
watch: {
  serverData(data) {
    if (data)
      this.loadImages()
  }
}
```

Comment: the bottom solution worked for me. I must improve my understanding in computed, mounted, etc cheers!